# jquery replace specific words on mouseover

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is my `image tag`

This is my jquery to get src

```
$('.hoverme').mouseover(function(){
        console.log($(this).attr('src'));
    });
```

Working good. Now on mouseover i need to change

src from

```
/images/image_107/thumb/Ubuntu-Wallpaper-HD.jpg?1380112803
```

to

```
/images/image_107/large/Ubuntu-Wallpaper-HD.jpg?1380112803
```

How can i achieve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use replace

```
 $('.hoverme').mouseover(function(){
       console.log($(this).attr('src').replace("thumb", "large" ));
 });
```

And if you want to make sure its the only thing thats getting replaced add "/" like

```
$('.hoverme').mouseover(function(){
       console.log($(this).attr('src').replace("/thumb/", "/large/" ));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just do:

```
$(this).attr('src').replace('/thumb/', '/large/');
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have to replace and then revert

```
$('.hoverme').hover(function () {
    $(this).attr('src', function (idx, src) {
        return src.replace('/thumb/', '/large/')
    })
}, function () {
    $(this).attr('src', function (idx, src) {
        return src.replace('/large/', '/thumb/')
    })
});
```

If it is one way

```
$('.hoverme').mouseenter(function () {
    $(this).attr('src', function (idx, src) {
        return src.replace('/thumb/', '/large/')
    })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution is this:

**HTML**

```
<img src="/images/image_107/thumb/Ubuntu-Wallpaper-HD.jpg?1380112803" data-large="/images/image_107/large/Ubuntu-Wallpaper-HD.jpg?1380112803" />
```

**jQuery**

```
$('img').mouseover(
    function()
    {
        var large = $(this).attr('data-large');
        var small = $(this).attr('src');

        $(this).attr('src', large);
        $(this).attr('data-large', small);
    }
);

// And for mouseout
$('img').mouseout(
    function()
    {
        var large = $(this).attr('src');
        var small = $(this).attr('data-large');

        $(this).attr('src', large);
        $(this).attr('data-large', small);
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

you could use replace

```
$('.hoverme').mouseover(function(){
        var src = $(this).attr('src');
        var newSrc = src.Replace("thumb", "large");
        $(this).attr('src', newSrc);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$('.hoverme').mouseover(function(){
        this.src="/images/image_107/large/Ubuntu-Wallpaper-HD.jpg?1380112803"
    });
```